# xbindkeysrc copy/paste buttons is weird in LibreOffice after updating from Ubuntu 18 to 19

Tags: upgrade, mouse, libreoffice, button, copy-and-paste

I upgraded from Ubuntu 18 to 19 and now Calc is pasting an image instead of the selected cells. With Writer instead, I need to copy twice in order to get what I wanted to copy in the first place. With the other programs such as the browser or simple editor, everything looks as it was.

I am using a mouse with 5 buttons and running the file ~/.xbindkeysrc to link the command to the mouse, with the content:

```
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key c' 'keyup Control_L'"
b:9

"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key v' 'keyup Control_L'"
b:8
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: You could be more specific about your Ubuntu releases, there is no Ubuntu 18; there is Ubuntu Core 18; but no Ubuntu Core 19.  Ubuntu 18.10 is tested to release-upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04, but if you upgraded from 18.04 to 19.04 or 19.10 directly, those were untested & unsupported paths so you accepted risks could be involved; stick to supported upgrade paths if you want the least risk.

Comment: See if using xdotool instead of xte fixes the issue.

Comment: @Gigiux you said 5 buttons.. b8 n b9?? have you configured to use mouse buttons 8 n 9 out of 5 physical buttons??

Comment: I did all the trajectory: ub. 18.04 -> ub. 18.10 -> ub. 19.04 -> ub. 19.10. B8 b9 were found with the terminal querying - I don't remember the commands by heart- but it worked till the other day

Comment: with xdotool it stopped working altogether...

Comment: It's a different syntax with xdotool